EF Core, do not track inluded child entities
I'm trying to disable tracking for related children entities. I have a model like below (simplified):
public class Request
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public List<RequestAnswer> RequestAnswers { get; set; } = [];
}

public class RequestAnswer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Answer { get; set; }
    public Guid RequestId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public Request Request { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Prompt { get; set; }

    public List<RequestAnswer> RequestAnswers { get; set; } = [];
}

The context is setup like this:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Ref: RequestAnswer.RequestId > Request.Id
    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
       .HasMany(e => e.RequestAnswers)
       .WithOne(e => e.Request)
       .HasForeignKey(e => e.RequestId)
       .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.Id);

    // Ref: RequestAnswer.QuestionId > Question.Id
    modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
       .HasMany(e => e.RequestAnswers)
       .WithOne(e => e.Question)
       .HasForeignKey(e => e.QuestionId)
       .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.Id);
}

When I query a request with their answers, I need to get the corresponding question entity as well (there are more fields that I actually need). My query looks like this:
var request = _db.Requests
                 .Where(r => r.Id == id)
                 .Include(r => r.RequestAnswers)
                 .ThenInclude(a => a.Question)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

This works well because now I can loop over the answers and access answer.Question.Prompt. I then need to update the status, so after I do request.StatusId = 2; I then call _db.Requests.Update(request); _db.SaveChanges(); EF Core does update the Request record.
The problem is that EF Core then updates all of the RequestAnswers (which I don't mind), but also the related Question database records (to the same values as nothing has been actually changed).
Is there a way to load the Request and Answers and keep tracking them, but not tracking the related Question entities? As far as I understand .AsNoTracking is all or nothing for one query result.
The main issue is the user running this piece of code only has SELECT permissions on the Question table and SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE on the other 2 tables, so updating the Request entity fails.
I am using .NET 8 and EF Core 8.
I could load the Question records separately as no tracking, but I would then need to match them manually with the questions and pass them around separately which I'm trying to avoid.

If nothing is being changed on those instances, then nothing should be saved. Sounds like there is more to this problem than you have told us. You shouldn't need to _db.Requests.Update if this is the same context instance. Perhaps you should investigate what exactly EF considers to be changed?

That's the thing, no value is actually changed. I'm only ever reading the Question properties. Given EF isn't thread safe, I've had to resort to multiple context instances (hence why I'm calling Update, but I would have thought it was smart enough to see if anything has actually changed. Is there no way of calling Update with a scope (only update the record I'm passing, not the decendants). Or should I just clear the list of Answer (given it's another context) so it doesn't look at related entities?

"DbSet.Update() Begins tracking the given entity and entries reachable from the given entity ... "

Simply don't call Update. You are using a tracking query so make the changes to the entities at whatever level you need and call SaveChanges. Update is for updating/inserting "detached" entities. If you have tracked entities, avoid falling back on Update, it defeats the purpose, updating all properties even if nothing actually changed.

Thanks, I removed the call to Update and that worked. I guess I didn't need to be too controlling of EF, it already does all the logic. It does mean we need to be careful with entities returned by EF as calling SaveChanges may update more records than we think (as we don't need to call Update)

I can't mark a comment as accepted answer.
But the issue is now resolved. I didn't need to call Update as EF already does tracking correctly.
